# Bootstrap form input alignment

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a responseive form with bootstrap.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='container-fluid'>
  <form class='form-horizontal'>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label class='control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12'>Product
          </label>
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <select class='form-control input-lg'>
              <option>
                Device
              </option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg'>Manage product
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label class='control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12'>Profile
          </label>
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <select class='form-control input-lg'>
              <option>123
              </option>                                
            </select>
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg'>Manage profile
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label class='control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12' for='from'>From
          </label>
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <input type='date' data-format='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control input-lg' value='2018-01-24' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label class='control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12' for='to'>To
          </label>
      <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <input type='date' data-format='yyyy-MM-dd' class='form-control input-lg' value='2018-01-26' />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12'>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-block btn-primary btn-lg'>Load
            </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Everything is how I want it, except that on medium devices (>= 992px, col-md-) or bigger I would like the 'From' and 'To' rows next to each other, so that the 'To' would be underneath the 'Manage profile' button. Any ides on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could combine the last `form-group` like this..

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">Product
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <select class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option>
                        Device
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Manage product
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-12">Profile
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <select class="form-control input-lg">
                    <option>123
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-lg">Manage profile
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3" for="from">From
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-9">
                <input type="date" data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" class="form-control input-lg" value="2018-01-24">
            </div>

            <label class="control-label col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-3" for="to">To
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-9">
                <input type="date" data-format="yyyy-MM-dd" class="form-control input-lg" value="2018-01-26">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-9 col-xs-12"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/FsKzmCSKdq

However, on the last 2 date inputs, they'll be too wide on `xs` screens so you probably still want those to stack into vertical columns.